# lstlisting breaks ifbool block

Tags: listings, conditionals, etoolbox

I have the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\newbool{xyz}
%\booltrue{xyz}
\boolfalse{xyz}

\begin{document}

\ifbool{xyz}{
    \section{XYZ explained}
    \newpage
}{
    \begin{lstlisting}
    %my code goes here
    \end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile the document, I get an error saying:

*Paragraph ended before \@lstlisting was complete.*

Compiling the example above results in the following error instead:

*TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].*

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem, stemming from the fact that [you can't have verbatim content as part of a macro argument](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-verbwithin.html). In your case, the verbatim content is a listing, and the macro is `\ifbool{<bool>}{<true>}{<false>}`.

However, [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\newbool{<bool>}` creates a primitive TeX `\if<bool>`, which you can use to condition. So, instead of using the macro-interface mentioned above, use the primitive interface `\if<bool><true>\else<false>\fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\newbool{xyz}% Creates \ifxyz; default is \xyzfalse
%\booltrue{xyz}% Sets \xyztrue

\begin{document}

\ifxyz% <true>
\section{XYZ explained}
\newpage
\else% <false>
\begin{lstlisting}
%my code goes here
\end{lstlisting}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works like a sharm!! thanks a lot @werner!